# Optimal class structure for characters in a play?

Tags: java, oop

I would like to model the basic structure of a play using java code. What would be the optimal way to organize classes and fields?

**What I need to do:**

I would like to be able to create an array (or `ArrayList`) of `Character` objects. A Character would be able to enter and exit the stage, accompanied by a boolean representing the Character's current state.

I need each Character to be able to reference every other Character instance, and have access to whether or not that Character is on the stage.

Essentially, the overarching problem is this: given a Character `A`, print a list of which characters never appear on stage at the same time as `A`.

My first idea was to have a `List` of Characters, and have each of those Characters have a `Hashtable` with a key for every other Character, and a boolean indicating whether the two ever appear on stage simultaneously. While this would probably work, I would basically have a list of lists. I feel that there should be a better solution, especially considering that every value is essentially repeated (A's reference to being on stage with B, and B's reference to A).

If anyone could offer a more efficient class/field structure, I would really appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: Looks rather simple. You are just missing an explicit `Stage` concept rather than trying to store state of all other characters in every characters. Do you have to simply answer if they are currently in the same stage or if they ever were on the same stage in the present and the past?

Comment: I guess correct place to ask this question is http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @plalx I really overlooked the `Stage` idea- I think I can implement a solution like that. And yes, present and past, but I don't think that'll be an issue. Thanks!

Comment: @NoahHolloway No problem. By the way, I think that your data structure is just fine, but I'd keep it within the `Stage` itself. It doesn't matter if the relationship is bidirectional. It's the easiest way to perform the lookup. I'd have a characters `Map<CharacterId, Map<CharacterId, Boolean>>` or `Map<CharacterId, Set<CharacterId>>` to maintain relationships within the stage.

Comment: You may have various ways of optimizing this, but this structure is very easy to implement so unless you have the need to optimize I'd choose simplicity. An example of premature optimization is that if you have less than 32 characters you could store all the enter/leave states as a series of bits were every bit represents the state of a character and use bitwise operators to check if 2 characters were present at the same time or not.

Comment: An example of premature optimization is that if you have less than 32 characters you could store all the enter/leave states as a series of bits were every bit represents the state of a character and use bitwise operators to check if 2 characters were present at the same time or not. 1: No characters (000), 2: Character 1 enters (100), 3: Character 3 enters (101). If you need to check if char 1 was there while 3 was there you loop all states and use a bitand operator with the mask (101).

Comment: Yeah, this is kind of just a visual way of organizing a dozen or so entries- I won't really have the need to optimize it. Thanks again.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dsLw862m/1/